# Corrupted raspberry pi partition

Tags: linux, filesystems

I've got a microSD card that was used in a Raspberry Pi running Hassio (smart home) image.

The main partition got corrupted and when running on a windows machine it asks me to format, which is probably not the right thing to do.
Is there any way of restoring the partition on windows? I think about quick formatting and then trying to recover the files.

Does this make sense?

Comment: It probably uses some non-Windows filesystem. Windows can happily overwrite it with its own filesystem but if recovery is your goal then this will only make things worse. Your first step should be investigating the card in Linux.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks, I'll try that